# SQL Error [500310] [42703]: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: column "engagement_time_msec" does not exist in events_20180626_temp;

Tags: sql, json, database, amazon-redshift

I am making this query

```
SELECT event_params FROM public.events_20180626_temp where event_name='user_engagement';
```

and It gives correct out as below.

```
{"firebase_screen_class": "SplashScreenActivity", "firebase_event_origin": "auto", "firebase_screen_id": "7757319118664517009", "engagement_time_msec": "3804"}
{"firebase_screen_class": "BaseActivity", "firebase_event_origin": "auto", "firebase_screen_id": "-8308759841787556451", "engagement_time_msec": "5184"}
{"firebase_screen_class": "SplashScreenActivity", "firebase_event_origin": "auto", "firebase_screen_id": "5605799982713019219", "engagement_time_msec": "2976"}
{"firebase_screen_class": "CreateTaleActivity", "firebase_event_origin": "auto", "firebase_screen_id": "5605799982713019221", "engagement_time_msec": "46937"}
{"firebase_screen_class": "TaleLocationActivity", "firebase_event_origin": "auto", "firebase_screen_id": "5605799982713019223", "engagement_time_msec": "2952"}
{"firebase_screen_class": "TalePhotoEditorActivity", "firebase_event_origin": "auto", "firebase_screen_id": "5605799982713019228", "engagement_time_msec": "2295"}
{"firebase_screen_class": "BaseActivity", "firebase_event_origin": "auto", "firebase_screen_id": "5605799982713019220", "engagement_time_msec": "10664"}
```

When I am changing query to extract the value of the key "engagement_time_msec" it says `engagement_time_msec` doesn't exists in the table. Here is the query for that.

```
select json_extract_path_text(event_params, "engagement_time_msec") from public.events_20180626_temp where event_name='user_engagement';
```

I confirmed if `event_params` column contains valid json string using the query below.

`select is_valid_json(event_params) from public.events_20180626_temp;`

It returned `true` for each row.

```
true
true
true
true
true
true
```

Can anybody help me out here?. I am totally new to redshift. Thanks.

FYI data type of column `event_params` is  `varchar(65553)`

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Had to use single quote instead of double qoute for the key `engagement_time_msec` I want to extract value of.

```
select json_extract_path_text(event_params, 'engagement_time_msec') from public.events_20180626_temp where event_name='user_engagement';
```